# How to remove bold in ToC, ideally without a package

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, bold

I am writing my thesis, using a document class unique to my university - based on the `article` class.  I have to remove ALL **bold** formatting in the Table of Contents, and for some reason I get an error that I can't figure out when I use the `tocloft` package.

To remove the **bold** in the title of the ToC, and rename it to Table of Contents, I used `\renewcommand`... but as you can see below, to get the title page formatted correctly, I just used `\bigskip` alot, and that seems to be what `tocloft` doesn't like:

```
\documentclass{csun}[12pt]
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\textnormal{Table of Contents}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{large}
\begin{center}
CALIFORNIA STATE UNIVERSITY, NORTHRIDGE
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
Fermi Coordinates and Relative Motion in Inflationary Power Law Cosmologies
\bigskip
\bigskip

A thesis submitted in partial fulfilment of the requirements

for the degree of Master of Science Mathematics

\bigskip

by

\bigskip

The Author

\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\vspace*{8 em}
December 2012
\pagebreak
\end{center}
\pagebreak

\chapter*{\textnormal{Dedications}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedications}
Dedication goes here.
\tableofcontents %makes a ToC with chapter names and page numbers bolded.
My thesis goes here.
\end{large}
\end{document}
```

Sorry that is a monster block of code, I realize that's not minimal, but I think it's relevant.  When I try to use `tocloft`, and hit go to error, it sends me to one of the `\bigskip`s.  The error message says:

```
Error: Command \c@lofdepth already defined.

Or name \end... illegal
```

Any suggestions for how to make `tocloft` work, or how to remove the **bold** formatting without `tocloft` would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the document class `csun`? The reason is that document elements like the ToC is highly dependent on the `\documentclass`, and could provide insight into *why* it doesn't work with [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft), or why you are using a bizillion `\bigskip`s.

Answer (score 2):

The link to the class package you are using is http://www.csun.edu/~mathgs/LaTex.html,  The class in the given link is now named `CSUNthesis.cls`. Your document will not compile with the code that you provided. You are required to supply the following information in your preamble since, according to the documentation, these are required.

```
\author{<author–name>}
\committee {<chair member>}{<2nd member>}{<3rd member>}
\title{<title of work>}
\coordinator{<coordinator–name>}
\submitted {<month>}{<year>}
\abstract{<abstract material>}
```

According to the given link, the `CSUNthesis.cls`

> "automatically produces a document which adheres to campus guidelines."

so, IMHO, it is best that you follow the documentation provided with the class file.

By the way, there is an optional `\dedication{<>}` command that you can use to typeset your dedication.

The code below does just fine and I see no boldfaced letters in the Table of Contents.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{CSUNthesis}
\author{Sam}
\committee{Jose}{Pepito}{Juan}
\title{Title}
\coordinator{The Coordinator}
\submitted{December}{2012}
\abstract{This is the abstract material and nothing more.}
\dedication{Dedication goes here.}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

If you got your `csun.cls` modified, perhaps you can provide a link to the modified class file.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]